# Find the $\int^{3+i}_0 \sin z\;dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

find the $\int^{3+i}_0 \sin z\;dz$

my attempt:

$\int^{3+i}_0 \sin z\;dz=\int^{3+i}_0 (\sin x \cos hy\;dx-\cos x\sin hy\;dy)$

is i am correct how to processed from here

Comment: That is $$\left[-\cos z\right]_{0}^{3+i}$$ since $\sin$ is an entire function. It is highly unclear where your $h$ comes from, or what is its purpose.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think he tried to split $z$ into real ($x$) and imaginary ($h$) parts.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio..yes i am trying that way

Comment: This is unnecessary by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire..thank you